# Filter the relation in the RouteModelBinding context in the controller method show()

Tags: laravel

I am working on a Laravel8 project with Route Model Binding. It is about Posts. Post has a **One To Many (Polymorphic) Relation** to the model Comment. Comments have a field approved. This is a Boolean.

How can I display the Post with its Comments that are approved === true. I know I could catch it in the blade with an if condition. But my goal is to filter the comments already in the controller.

```
    public function show(Post $post)
    {  
        dd( $post->comments );        
        return view('post', ['post' => $post]);
    }
```

**Comment migration, - Model:**

```
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();            
        $table->text('comment_content');
        ...
        $table->boolean('approved')->default(false);
        $table->integer('commentable_id');
        $table->string('commentable_type');            
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Comment Model
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

**Post Model**

```
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(PostComment::class, 'commentable');
    }
```

Expected only the Comments which approved.

Comment: I don't see approved  in your migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if it is morph relation, you can load it using [load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) method:

```
$post->load(['comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('approved', true);
}]);
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that it is a polymorphic relationship. I updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::loadMorph(), 1 passed in /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php on line 40 and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: sorry, I don't have this relation in my projects to test, please try my last try!!

Comment: Unfortunately no. Thank you for your time. I'll add the Post Model to my question.

Comment: @MaikLowrey, I finally was able to test it, it works fine, but i do not see approved column in your migration

Comment: You are right. i had mistakenly deleted it. I have added it again.

Comment: fine, have you test my answer? cause if did, it worked fine

Comment: Oh no! It was a spelling mistake. Sorry. Instead of `approved` I had `appoved`. Thank you for your time and help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can load in only approved comments on the relationship like so:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(PostComment::class, 'commentable')
        ->where('approved', 1);
}
```

`MorphMany` is from Laravel's `HasRelationships` class, and you should be able to tag on a `where` condition to filter it as you need.

Comment: @part-ring Tanks, it works! unfortunately, you cannot accept both answers. Otherwise I would have accepted yours too. Thank you ...